# Big Query / SQL finding "new" data in a date range

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a pretty big event log with columns:

```
id, timestamp, text, user_id
```

The text field contains a variety of things, like:

```
Road: This is the road name
City: This is the city name
Type: This is a type
etc..
```

I would like to get the result to the following:

```
Given a start and end date, how many **new** users used a road (that haven't before) grouped by road.
```

I've got various parts of this working fine (like the total amount of users, the grouping by, date range and so on. The SQL for getting the new users is alluding me though, having tried solutions like SELECT AS STRUCT on sub queries amongst other things.

Ultimately, I'd love to see a result like:

```
road, total_users, new_users
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results in *text* table formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want something like this:

```
select road, counif(seqnum = 1) as new_users, count(distinct user_id) as num_users
from (select l.*,
             row_number() over (partition by l.user_id, l.text order by l.timestamp) as seqnum
      from log l
      where l.type = 'Road'
     ) l
where timestamp >= @timestamp1 and timestamp < @timestamp2
group by road;
```

This assumes that you have a column that specifies the type (i.e. "road") and another column with the name of the road (i.e. "Champs-Elysees").

Comment: Let me try and work with this, I (they..) don't have that no, it's just a big event log with the "types" at the beginning of a text blob. I used starts_with / ends_with A LOT to group things :-(

Comment: Thanks, this did the magic with a few adjustments. Appreciate the help!